# When to use blocking and non-blocking assignments

Tags: verilog

I am having a really hard time to understand where to use blocking and non-blocking assignments. I have read many answers regarding this on this site and have also referred to book on Verilog by "Samir Palnitkar". But when I sit to actually implement some circuit, I am not able to decide which one to use.

I have following questions regarding this:

a) In a sequential circuit, say Synchronous 4-bit counter implemented using JK flip-flops, we need to use two & gates and the output of one & gate is used as the input of the other. Now, I follow the thumb rule that I should use <= for sequential circuts and should not mix = and <= assignments in an @always block.

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
    begin
        if(en)
        begin
            if(rst)
                q<=4'b0000;
            else
            begin
                q[0]<=(~q[0]);

                if(q[0]==1)
                    q[1]<=(~q[1]);

                if(q[0]&q[1]==1)
                    q[2]<=~q[2];

                if(q[0]&q[1]&q[2]==1)
                    q[3]=~q[3];
            end
        end
    end
```

In the above code for the same circuit, what if I want to store the o/p of q[0]&q[1] in another register and then use it to find q[0]&q[1]&q[2]? If I use <=, I may end up getting wrong value of q[0]&q[1]&q[2].

How should I store the intermediate outputs and use them as inputs in the sequential circuit (May be needed for complex circuits)?

b) What are some rules/guidlines that I should follow so that I don't encounter some race condition or other undesired o/p from my code?

Comment: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf go thru this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not understanding the rule correctly. You must not mix `=` and `<=` to the ***same*** variable within an `always` block.

And yes, generally you should use non-blocking `<=` assignments to sequential logic. You ***must*** us a non-blocking assignment if one `always @(posedge clock)` block writes, and another `always @(posedge clock)` reads the same variable, or combinatorial expression of the same variable).

The synthesis tool makes the variable sequential if one of the following is true:

1. The variable is written with a non-blocking assignment `<=`
2. The variable is read before written within the block
3. The variable is read somewhere else outside the block

Otherwise it becomes combinational logic.

Comment: Thanks, got it. One more thing, should I always put the combinational part in one block and the sequential part in the other block, so that it's easy to understand the code?

Comment: That is another frequently asked question with highly opinionated answers. Many people do choose to separate the block to avoid any possible confusion.